# How to select the products which are not shipped in the month of august

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database in which I have tables with relationships. So, I need the products that are not shipped in the month of August.

I know how to select the list of products which are shipped in the month of August. But how to select the products which are not shipped in August?

Comment: sample data and output will help you a lot

Comment: I've added an answer based on assumptions, it would be good for you to add some more information to give you a proper solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I got the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM things 
   WHERE MONTH(shippedDate) <> 8
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing  your = with <>. Post your query here. so that everyone can have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the query-

```
SELECT * FROM tblProducts
WHERE Month <> 'August'
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the format in which the date are stored in shippedDate column
Also if the shippedDate column is of datatype date,smalldatetime or datetime then
the below query by Ahsan is correct `SELECT * FROM things 
   WHERE MONTH(shippedDate) <> 8`